# Multiple scenes playing at once in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So the problem is i've just added a simple menu system to my game and it seems to load both scenes at the same time. The game is running in the background which is annoying, but somehow after pressing play it resets the game scene and starts playing the game normally. In the build settings the gamescene is named pretty weirdly, but every time i drag my game scene from the hierarchy, it gives me that name in the build settings. Any tips on how to make the scenes work properly?

[image: Image of my Build settings]

```
public class MainMenuN : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
    public void QuitGame (){
        Debug.Log("QUIT");
        Application.Quit();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you have currently both scenes loaded in the Hierarchy!

So when pressing play to enter the playmode both scenes are loaded and running.

Then after pressing the button your do `SceneManager.LoadScene` without passing in the `mode` parameter, so it uses the default mode which is [`Single`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Single.html).

> Closes all current loaded Scenes and loads a Scene.

That's why it works after that since this makes all currently loaded scenes be unloaded and the target scene loaded.

---

This [Multi Scene Editing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html) is a pure editor feature and will not behave like that in a build where only the very first scene from the settings will be loaded.

Especially be careful with cross scene references!

---

For testing correctly in the editor and replicate the same behavior your app will have after building save and then remove the second scene (`Ropesgame`) from the Hierarchy.